# calendar is not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJLnC.png)

when I try to  click on field of type Date-time to pick time from date-picker  my calendar dose not display properly as image show 
how i can fix that issue ?

this is my code for datepicker

```
!function(a,b){function c(){return new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date,arguments))}function d(){var a=new Date;return c(a.getFullYear(),a.getMonth(),a.getDate())}function e(a,b){return a.getUTCFullYear()===b.getUTCFullYear()&&a.getUTCMonth()===b.getUTCMonth()&&a.getUTCDate()===b.getUTCDate()}function f(a){return function(){return this[a].apply(this,arguments)}}function g(b,c){function d(a,b){return b.toLowerCase()}var e,f=a(b).data(),g={},h=new RegExp("^"+c.toLowerCase()+"([A-Z])");c=new RegExp("^"+c.toLowerCase());for(var i in f)c.test(i)&&(e=i.replace(h,d),g[e]=f[i]);return g}function h(b){var c={};if(p[b]||(b=b.split("-")[0],p[b])){var d=p[b];return a.each(o,function(a,b){b in d&&(c[b]=d[b])}),c}}var i=function(){var b={get:function(a){return this.slice(a)[0]},contains:function(a){for(var b=a&&a.valueOf(),c=0,d=this.length;d>c;c++)if(this[c].valueOf()===b)return c;return-1},remove:function(a){this.splice(a,1)},replace:function(b){b&&(a.isArray(b)||(b=[b]),this.clear(),this.push.apply(this,b))},clear:function(){this.length=0},copy:function(){var a=new i;return a.replace(this),a}};return function(){var c=[];return c.push.apply(c,arguments),a.extend(c,b),c}}(),j=function(b,c){this._process_options(c),this.dates=new i,this.viewDate=this.o.defaultViewDate,this.focusDate=null,this.element=a(b),this.isInline=!1,this.isInput=this.element.is("input"),this.component=this.element.hasClass("date")?this.element.find(".add-on, .input-group-addon, .btn"):!1,this.hasInput=this.component&&this.element.find("input").length,this.component&&0===this.component.length&&(this.component=!1),this.picker=a(q.template),this._buildEvents(),this._attachEvents(),this.isInline?this.picker.addClass("datepicker-inline").appendTo(this.element):this.picker.addClass("datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu"),this.o.rtl&&this.picker.addClass("datepicker-rtl"),this.viewMode=this.o.startView,this.o.calendarWeeks&&this.picker.find("tfoot .today, tfoot .clear").attr("colspan",function(a,b){return parseInt(b)+1}),this._allow_update=!1,this.setStartDate(this._o.startDate),this.setEndDate(this._o.endDate),this.setDaysOfWeekDisabled(this.o.daysOfWeekDisabled),this.setDatesDisabled(this.o.datesDisabled),this.fillDow(),this.fillMonths(),this._allow_update=!0,this.update(),this.showMode(),this.isInline&&this.show()};j.prototype={constructor:j,_process_options:function(e){this._o=a.extend({},this._o,e);var f=this.o=a.extend({},this._o),g=f.language;switch(p[g]||(g=g.split("-")[0],p[g]||(g=n.language)),f.language=g,f.startView){case 2:case"decade":f.startView=2;break;case 1:case"year":f.startView=1;break;default:f.startView=0}switch(f.minViewMode){case 1:case"months":f.minViewMode=1;break;case 2:case"years":f.minViewMode=2;break;default:f.minViewMode=0}f.startView=Math.max(f.startView,f.minViewMode),f.multidate!==!0&&(f.multidate=Number(f.multidate)||!1,f.multidate!==!1&&(f.multidate=Math.max(0,f.multidate))),f.multidateSeparator=String(f.multidateSeparator),f.weekStart%=7,f.weekEnd=(f.weekStart+6)%7;var h=q.parseFormat(f.format);if(f.startDate!==-1/0&&(f.startDate=f.startDate?f.startDate instanceof Date?this._local_to_utc(this._zero_time(f.startDate)):q.parseDate(f.startDate,h,f.language):-1/0),1/0!==f.endDate&&(f.endDate=f.endDate?f.endDate instanceof Date?this._local_to_utc(this._zero_time(f.endDate)):q.parseDate(f.endDate,h,f.language):1/0),f.daysOfWeekDisabled=f.daysOfWeekDisabled||[],a.isArray(f.daysOfWeekDisabled)||(f.daysOfWeekDisabled=f.daysOfWeekDisabled.split(/[,\s]*/)),f.daysOfWeekDisabled=a.map(f.daysOfWeekDisabled,function(a){return parseInt(a,10)}),f.datesDisabled=f.datesDisabled||[],!a.isArray(f.datesDisabled)){var i=[];i.push(q.parseDate(f.datesDisabled,h,f.language)),f.datesDisabled=i}f.datesDisabled=a.map(f.datesDisabled,function(a){return q.parseDate(a,h,f.language)});var j=String(f.orientation).toLowerCase().split(/\s+/g),k=f.orientation.toLowerCase();if(j=a.grep(j,function(a){return/^auto|left|right|top|bottom$/.test(a)}),f.orientation={x:"auto",y:"auto"},k&&"auto"!==k)if(1===j.length)switch(j[0]){case"top":case"bottom":f.orientation.y=j[0];break;case"left":case"right":f.orientation.x=j[0]}else k=a.grep(j,function(a){return/^left|right$/.test(a)}),f.orientation.x=k[0]||"auto",k=a.grep(j,function(a){return/^top|bottom$/.test(a)}),f.orientation.y=k[0]||"auto";else;if(f.defaultViewDate){var l=f.defaultViewDate.year||(new Date).getFullYear(),m=f.defaultViewDate.month||0,o=f.defaultViewDate.day||1;f.defaultViewDate=c(l,m,o)}else f.defaultViewDate=d();f.showOnFocus=f.showOnFocus!==b?f.showOnFocus:!0},_events:[],_secondaryEvents:[],_applyEvents:function(a){for(var c,d,e,f=0;f<a.length;f++)c=a[f][0],2===a[f].length?(d=b,e=a[f][1]):3===a[f].length&&(d=a[f][1],e=a[f][2]),c.on(e,d)},_unapplyEvents:function(a){for(var c,d,e,f=0;f<a.length;f++)c=a[f][0],2===a[f].length?(e=b,d=a[f][1]):3===a[f].length&&(e=a[f][1],d=a[f][2]),c.off(d,e)},_buildEvents:function(){var b={keyup:a.proxy(function(b){-1===a.inArray(b.keyCode,[27,37,39,38,40,32,13,9])&&this.update()},this),keydown:a.proxy(this.keydown,this)};this.o.showOnFocus===!0&&(b.focus=a.proxy(this.show,this)),this.isInput?this._events=[[this.element,b]]:this.component&&this.hasInput?this._events=[[this.element.find("input"),b],[this.component,{click:a.proxy(this.show,this)}]]:this.element.is("div")?this.isInline=!0:this._events=[[this.element,{click:a.proxy(this.show,this)}]],this._events.push([this.element,"*",{blur:a.proxy(function(a){this._focused_from=a.target},this)}],[this.element,{blur:a.proxy(function(a){this._focused_from=a.target},this)}]),this._secondaryEvents=[[this.picker,{click:a.proxy(this.click,this)}],[a(window),{resize:a.proxy(this.place,this)}],[a(document),{"mousedown touchstart":a.proxy(function(a){this.element.is(a.target)||this.element.find(a.target).length||this.picker.is(a.target)||this.picker.find(a.target).length||this.hide()},this)}]]},_attachEvents:function(){this._detachEvents(),this._applyEvents(this._events)},_detachEvents:function(){this._unapplyEvents(this._events)},_attachSecondaryEvents:function(){this._detachSecondaryEvents(),this._applyEvents(this._secondaryEvents)},_detachSecondaryEvents:function(){this._unapplyEvents(this._secondaryEvents)},_trigger:function(b,c){var d=c||this.dates.get(-1),e=this._utc_to_local(d);this.element.trigger({type:b,date:e,dates:a.map(this.dates,this._utc_to_local),format:a.proxy(function(a,b){0===arguments.length?(a=this.dates.length-1,b=this.o.format):"string"==typeof a&&(b=a,a=this.dates.length-1),b=b||this.o.format;var c=this.dates.get(a);return q.formatDate(c,b,this.o.language)},this)})},show:function(){return this.element.attr("readonly")&&this.o.enableOnReadonly===!1?void 0:(this.isInline||this.picker.appendTo(this.o.container),this.place(),this.picker.show(),this._attachSecondaryEvents(),this._trigger("show"),(window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints||"ontouchstart"in document)&&this.o.disableTouchKeyboard&&a(this.element).blur(),this)},hide:function(){return this.isInline?this:this.picker.is(":visible")?(this.focusDate=null,this.picker.hide().detach(),this._detachSecondaryEvents(),this.viewMode=this.o.startView,this.showMode(),this.o.forceParse&&(this.isInput&&this.element.val()||this.hasInput&&this.element.find("input").val())&&this.setValue(),this._trigger("hide"),this):this},remove:function(){return this.hide(),this._detachEvents(),this._detachSecondaryEvents(),this.picker.remove(),delete this.element.data().datepicker,this.isInput||delete this.element.data().date,this},_utc_to_local:function(a){return a&&new Date(a.getTime()+6e4*a.getTimezoneOffset())},_local_to_utc:function(a){return a&&new Date(a.getTime()-6e4*a.getTimezoneOffset())},_zero_time:function(a){return a&&new Date(a.getFullYear(),a.getMonth(),a.getDate())},_zero_utc_time:function(a){return a&&new Date(Date.UTC(a.getUTCFullYear(),a.getUTCMonth(),a.getUTCDate()))},getDates:function(){return a.map(this.dates,this._utc_to_local)},getUTCDates:function(){return a.map(this.dates,function(a){return new Date(a)})},getDate:function(){return this._utc_to_local(this.getUTCDate())},getUTCDate:function(){var a=this.dates.get(-1);return"undefined"!=typeof a?new Date(a):null},clearDates:function(){var a;this.isInput?a=this.element:this.component&&(a=this.element.find("input")),a&&a.val("").change(),this.update(),this._trigger("changeDate"),this.o.autoclose&&this.hide()},setDates:function(){var b=a.isArray(arguments[0])?arguments[0]:arguments;return this.update.apply(this,b),this._trigger("changeDate"),this.setValue(),this},setUTCDates:function(){var b=a.isArray(arguments[0])?arguments[0]:arguments;return this.update.apply(this,a.map(b,this._utc_to_local)),this._trigger("changeDate"),this.setValue(),this},setDate:f("setDates"),setUTCDate:f("setUTCDates"),setValue:function(){var a=this.getFormattedDate();return this.isInput?this.element.val(a).change():this.component&&this.element.find("input").val(a).change(),this},getFormattedDate:function(c){c===b&&(c=this.o.format);var d=this.o.language;return a.map(this.dates,function(a){return q.formatDate(a,c,d)}).join(this.o.multidateSeparator)},setStartDate:function(a){return this._process_options({startDate:a}),this.update(),this.updateNavArrows(),this},setEndDate:function(a){return this._process_options({endDate:a}),this.update(),this.updateNavArrows(),this},setDaysOfWeekDisabled:function(a){return this._process_options({daysOfWeekDisabled:a}),this.update(),this.updateNavArrows(),this},setDatesDisabled:function(a){this._process_options({datesDisabled:a}),this.update(),this.updateNavArrows()},place:function(){if(this.isInline)return this;var b=this.picker.outerWidth(),c=this.picker.outerHeight(),d=10,e=a(this.o.container).width(),f=a(this.o.container).height(),g=a(this.o.container).scrollTop(),h=a(this.o.container).offset(),i=[];this.element.parents().each(function(){var b=a(this).css("z-index");"auto"!==b&&0!==b&&i.push(parseInt(b))});var j=Math.max.apply(Math,i)+10,k=this.component?this.component.parent().offset():this.element.offset(),l=this.component?this.component.outerHeight(!0):this.element.outerHeight(!1),m=this.component?this.component.outerWidth(!0):this.element.outerWidth(!1),n=k.left-h.left,o=k.top-h.top;this.picker.removeClass("datepicker-orient-top datepicker-orient-bottom datepicker-orient-right datepicker-orient-left"),"auto"!==this.o.orientation.x?(this.picker.addClass("datepicker-orient-"+this.o.orientation.x),"right"===this.o.orientation.x&&(n-=b-m)):k.left<0?(this.picker.addClass("datepicker-orient-left"),n-=k.left-d):n+b>e?(this.picker.addClass("datepicker-orient-right"),n=k.left+m-b):this.picker.addClass("datepicker-orient-left");var p,q,r=this.o.orientation.y;if("auto"===r&&(p=-g+o-c,q=g+f-(o+l+c),r=Math.max(p,q)===q?"top":"bottom"),this.picker.addClass("datepicker-orient-"+r),"top"===r?o+=l:o-=c+parseInt(this.picker.css("padding-top")),this.o.rtl){var s=e-(n+m);this.picker.css({top:o,right:s,zIndex:j})}else this.picker.css({top:o,left:n,zIndex:j});return this},_allow_update:!0,update:function(){if(!this._allow_update)return this;var b=this.dates.copy(),c=[],d=!1;return arguments.length?(a.each(arguments,a.proxy(function(a,b){b instanceof Date&&(b=this._local_to_utc(b)),c.push(b)},this)),d=!0):(c=this.isInput?this.element.val():this.element.data("date")||this.element.find("input").val(),c=c&&this.o.multidate?c.split(this.o.multidateSeparator):[c],delete this.element.data().date),c=a.map(c,a.proxy(function(a){return q.parseDate(a,this.o.format,this.o.language)},this)),c=a.grep(c,a.proxy(function(a){return a<this.o.startDate||a>this.o.endDate||!a},this),!0),this.dates.replace(c),this.dates.length?this.viewDate=new Date(this.dates.get(-1)):this.viewDate<this.o.startDate?this.viewDate=new Date(this.o.startDate):this.viewDate>this.o.endDate&&(this.viewDate=new Date(this.o.endDate)),d?this.setValue():c.length&&String(b)!==String(this.dates)&&this._trigger("changeDate"),!this.dates.length&&b.length&&this._trigger("clearDate"),this.fill(),this},fillDow:function(){var a=this.o.weekStart,b="<tr>";if(this.o.calendarWeeks){this.picker.find(".datepicker-days thead tr:first-child .datepicker-switch").attr("colspan",function(a,b){return parseInt(b)+1});var c='<th class="cw">&#160;</th>';b+=c}for(;a<this.o.weekStart+7;)b+='<th class="dow">'+p[this.o.language].daysMin[a++%7]+"</th>";b+="</tr>",this.picker.find(".datepicker-days thead").append(b)},fillMonths:function(){for(var a="",b=0;12>b;)a+='<span class="month">'+p[this.o.language].monthsShort[b++]+"</span>";this.picker.find(".datepicker-months td").html(a)},setRange:function(b){b&&b.length?this.range=a.map(b,function(a){return a.valueOf()}):delete this.range,this.fill()},getClassNames:function(b){var c=[],d=this.viewDate.getUTCFullYear(),f=this.viewDate.getUTCMonth(),g=new Date;return b.getUTCFullYear()<d||b.getUTCFullYear()===d&&b.getUTCMonth()<f?c.push("old"):(b.getUTCFullYear()>d||b.getUTCFullYear()===d&&b.getUTCMonth()>f)&&c.push("new"),this.focusDate&&b.valueOf()===this.focusDate.valueOf()&&c.push("focused"),this.o.todayHighlight&&b.getUTCFullYear()===g.getFullYear()&&b.getUTCMonth()===g.getMonth()&&b.getUTCDate()===g.getDate()&&c.push("today"),-1!==this.dates.contains(b)&&c.push("active"),(b.valueOf()<this.o.startDate||b.valueOf()>this.o.endDate||-1!==a.inArray(b.getUTCDay(),this.o.daysOfWeekDisabled))&&c.push("disabled"),this.o.datesDisabled.length>0&&a.grep(this.o.datesDisabled,function(a){return e(b,a)}).length>0&&c.push("disabled","disabled-date"),this.range&&(b>this.range[0]&&b<this.range[this.range.length-1]&&c.push("range"),-1!==a.inArray(b.valueOf(),this.range)&&c.push("selected")),c},fill:function(){var d,e=new Date(this.viewDate),f=e.getUTCFullYear(),g=e.getUTCMonth(),h=this.o.startDate!==-1/0?this.o.startDate.getUTCFullYear():-1/0,i=this.o.startDate!==-1/0?this.o.startDate.getUTCMonth():-1/0,j=1/0!==this.o.endDate?this.o.endDate.getUTCFullYear():1/0,k=1/0!==this.o.endDate?this.o.endDate.getUTCMonth():1/0,l=p[this.o.language].today||p.en.today||"",m=p[this.o.language].clear||p.en.clear||"";if(!isNaN(f)&&!isNaN(g)){this.picker.find(".datepicker-days thead .datepicker-switch").text(p[this.o.language].months[g]+" "+f),this.picker.find("tfoot .today").text(l).toggle(this.o.todayBtn!==!1),this.picker.find("tfoot .clear").text(m).toggle(this.o.clearBtn!==!1),this.updateNavArrows(),this.fillMonths();var n=c(f,g-1,28),o=q.getDaysInMonth(n.getUTCFullYear(),n.getUTCMonth());n.setUTCDate(o),n.setUTCDate(o-(n.getUTCDay()-this.o.weekStart+7)%7);var r=new Date(n);r.setUTCDate(r.getUTCDate()+42),r=r.valueOf();for(var s,t=[];n.valueOf()<r;){if(n.getUTCDay()===this.o.weekStart&&(t.push("<tr>"),this.o.calendarWeeks)){var u=new Date(+n+(this.o.weekStart-n.getUTCDay()-7)%7*864e5),v=new Date(Number(u)+(11-u.getUTCDay())%7*864e5),w=new Date(Number(w=c(v.getUTCFullYear(),0,1))+(11-w.getUTCDay())%7*864e5),x=(v-w)/864e5/7+1;t.push('<td class="cw">'+x+"</td>")}if(s=this.getClassNames(n),s.push("day"),this.o.beforeShowDay!==a.noop){var y=this.o.beforeShowDay(this._utc_to_local(n));y===b?y={}:"boolean"==typeof y?y={enabled:y}:"string"==typeof y&&(y={classes:y}),y.enabled===!1&&s.push("disabled"),y.classes&&(s=s.concat(y.classes.split(/\s+/))),y.tooltip&&(d=y.tooltip)}s=a.unique(s),t.push('<td class="'+s.join(" ")+'"'+(d?' title="'+d+'"':"")+">"+n.getUTCDate()+"</td>"),d=null,n.getUTCDay()===this.o.weekEnd&&t.push("</tr>"),n.setUTCDate(n.getUTCDate()+1)}this.picker.find(".datepicker-days tbody").empty().append(t.join(""));var z=this.picker.find(".datepicker-months").find("th:eq(1)").text(f).end().find("span").removeClass("active");if(a.each(this.dates,function(a,b){b.getUTCFullYear()===f&&z.eq(b.getUTCMonth()).addClass("active")}),(h>f||f>j)&&z.addClass("disabled"),f===h&&z.slice(0,i).addClass("disabled"),f===j&&z.slice(k+1).addClass("disabled"),this.o.beforeShowMonth!==a.noop){var A=this;a.each(z,function(b,c){if(!a(c).hasClass("disabled")){var d=new Date(f,b,1),e=A.o.beforeShowMonth(d);e===!1&&a(c).addClass("disabled")}})}t="",f=10*parseInt(f/10,10);var B=this.picker.find(".datepicker-years").find("th:eq(1)").text(f+"-"+(f+9)).end().find("td");f-=1;for(var C,D=a.map(this.dates,function(a){return a.getUTCFullYear()}),E=-1;11>E;E++)C=["year"],-1===E?C.push("old"):10===E&&C.push("new"),-1!==a.inArray(f,D)&&C.push("active"),(h>f||f>j)&&C.push("disabled"),t+='<span class="'+C.join(" ")+'">'+f+"</span>",f+=1;B.html(t)}},updateNavArrows:function(){if(this._allow_update){var a=new Date(this.viewDate),b=a.getUTCFullYear(),c=a.getUTCMonth();switch(this.viewMode){case 0:this.picker.find(".prev").css(this.o.startDate!==-1/0&&b<=this.o.startDate.getUTCFullYear()&&c<=this.o.startDate.getUTCMonth()?{visibility:"hidden"}:{visibility:"visible"}),this.picker.find(".next").css(1/0!==this.o.endDate&&b>=this.o.endDate.getUTCFullYear()&&c>=this.o.endDate.getUTCMonth()?{visibility:"hidden"}:{visibility:"visible"});break;case 1:case 2:this.picker.find(".prev").css(this.o.startDate!==-1/0&&b<=this.o.startDate.getUTCFullYear()?{visibility:"hidden"}:{visibility:"visible"}),this.picker.find(".next").css(1/0!==this.o.endDate&&b>=this.o.endDate.getUTCFullYear()?{visibility:"hidden"}:{visibility:"visible"})}}},click:function(b){b.preventDefault();var d,e,f,g=a(b.target).closest("span, td, th");if(1===g.length)switch(g[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()){case"th":switch(g[0].className){case"datepicker-switch":this.showMode(1);break;case"prev":case"next":var h=q.modes[this.viewMode].navStep*("prev"===g[0].className?-1:1);switch(this.viewMode){case 0:this.viewDate=this.moveMonth(this.viewDate,h),this._trigger("changeMonth",this.viewDate);break;case 1:case 2:this.viewDate=this.moveYear(this.viewDate,h),1===this.viewMode&&this._trigger("changeYear",this.viewDate)}this.fill();break;case"today":var i=new Date;i=c(i.getFullYear(),i.getMonth(),i.getDate(),0,0,0),this.showMode(-2);var j="linked"===this.o.todayBtn?null:"view";this._setDate(i,j);break;case"clear":this.clearDates()}break;case"span":g.hasClass("disabled")||(this.viewDate.setUTCDate(1),g.hasClass("month")?(f=1,e=g.parent().find("span").index(g),d=this.viewDate.getUTCFullYear(),this.viewDate.setUTCMonth(e),this._trigger("changeMonth",this.viewDate),1===this.o.minViewMode&&this._setDate(c(d,e,f))):(f=1,e=0,d=parseInt(g.text(),10)||0,this.viewDate.setUTCFullYear(d),this._trigger("changeYear",this.viewDate),2===this.o.minViewMode&&this._setDate(c(d,e,f))),this.showMode(-1),this.fill());break;case"td":g.hasClass("day")&&!g.hasClass("disabled")&&(f=parseInt(g.text(),10)||1,d=this.viewDate.getUTCFullYear(),e=this.viewDate.getUTCMonth(),g.hasClass("old")?0===e?(e=11,d-=1):e-=1:g.hasClass("new")&&(11===e?(e=0,d+=1):e+=1),this._setDate(c(d,e,f)))}this.picker.is(":visible")&&this._focused_from&&a(this._focused_from).focus(),delete this._focused_from},_toggle_multidate:function(a){var b=this.dates.contains(a);if(a||this.dates.clear(),-1!==b?(this.o.multidate===!0||this.o.multidate>1||this.o.toggleActive)&&this.dates.remove(b):this.o.multidate===!1?(this.dates.clear(),this.dates.push(a)):this.dates.push(a),"number"==typeof this.o.multidate)for(;this.dates.length>this.o.multidate;)this.dates.remove(0)},_setDate:function(a,b){b&&"date"!==b||this._toggle_multidate(a&&new Date(a)),b&&"view"!==b||(this.viewDate=a&&new Date(a)),this.fill(),this.setValue(),b&&"view"===b||this._trigger("changeDate");var c;this.isInput?c=this.element:this.component&&(c=this.element.find("input")),c&&c.change(),!this.o.autoclose||b&&"date"!==b||this.hide()},moveMonth:function(a,c){if(!a)return b;if(!c)return a;var d,e,f=new Date(a.valueOf()),g=f.getUTCDate(),h=f.getUTCMonth(),i=Math.abs(c);if(c=c>0?1:-1,1===i)e=-1===c?function(){return f.getUTCMonth()===h}:function(){return f.getUTCMonth()!==d},d=h+c,f.setUTCMonth(d),(0>d||d>11)&&(d=(d+12)%12);else{for(var j=0;i>j;j++)f=this.moveMonth(f,c);d=f.getUTCMonth(),f.setUTCDate(g),e=function(){return d!==f.getUTCMonth()}}for(;e();)f.setUTCDate(--g),f.setUTCMonth(d);return f},moveYear:function(a,b){return this.moveMonth(a,12*b)},dateWithinRange:function(a){return a>=this.o.startDate&&a<=this.o.endDate},keydown:function(a){if(!this.picker.is(":visible"))return void(27===a.keyCode&&this.show());var b,c,e,f=!1,g=this.focusDate||this.viewDate;switch(a.keyCode){case 27:this.focusDate?(this.focusDate=null,this.viewDate=this.dates.get(-1)||this.viewDate,this.fill()):this.hide(),a.preventDefault();break;case 37:case 39:if(!this.o.keyboardNavigation)break;b=37===a.keyCode?-1:1,a.ctrlKey?(c=this.moveYear(this.dates.get(-1)||d(),b),e=this.moveYear(g,b),this._trigger("changeYear",this.viewDate)):a.shiftKey?(c=this.moveMonth(this.dates.get(-1)||d(),b),e=this.moveMonth(g,b),this._trigger("changeMonth",this.viewDate)):(c=new Date(this.dates.get(-1)||d()),c.setUTCDate(c.getUTCDate()+b),e=new Date(g),e.setUTCDate(g.getUTCDate()+b)),this.dateWithinRange(e)&&(this.focusDate=this.viewDate=e,this.setValue(),this.fill(),a.preventDefault());break;case 38:case 40:if(!this.o.keyboardNavigation)break;b=38===a.keyCode?-1:1,a.ctrlKey?(c=this.moveYear(this.dates.get(-1)||d(),b),e=this.moveYear(g,b),this._trigger("changeYear",this.viewDate)):a.shiftKey?(c=this.moveMonth(this.dates.get(-1)||d(),b),e=this.moveMonth(g,b),this._trigger("changeMonth",this.viewDate)):(c=new Date(this.dates.get(-1)||d()),c.setUTCDate(c.getUTCDate()+7*b),e=new Date(g),e.setUTCDate(g.getUTCDate()+7*b)),this.dateWithinRange(e)&&(this.focusDate=this.viewDate=e,this.setValue(),this.fill(),a.preventDefault());break;case 32:break;case 13:g=this.focusDate||this.dates.get(-1)||this.viewDate,this.o.keyboardNavigation&&(this._toggle_multidate(g),f=!0),this.focusDate=null,this.viewDate=this.dates.get(-1)||this.viewDate,this.setValue(),this.fill(),this.picker.is(":visible")&&(a.preventDefault(),"function"==typeof a.stopPropagation?a.stopPropagation():a.cancelBubble=!0,this.o.autoclose&&this.hide());break;case 9:this.focusDate=null,this.viewDate=this.dates.get(-1)||this.viewDate,this.fill(),this.hide()}if(f){this._trigger(this.dates.length?"changeDate":"clearDate");var h;this.isInput?h=this.element:this.component&&(h=this.element.find("input")),h&&h.change()}},showMode:function(a){a&&(this.viewMode=Math.max(this.o.minViewMode,Math.min(2,this.viewMode+a))),this.picker.children("div").hide().filter(".datepicker-"+q.modes[this.viewMode].clsName).css("display","block"),this.updateNavArrows()}};var k=function(b,c){this.element=a(b),this.inputs=a.map(c.inputs,function(a){return a.jquery?a[0]:a}),delete c.inputs,m.call(a(this.inputs),c).bind("changeDate",a.proxy(this.dateUpdated,this)),this.pickers=a.map(this.inputs,function(b){return a(b).data("datepicker")}),this.updateDates()};k.prototype={updateDates:function(){this.dates=a.map(this.pickers,function(a){return a.getUTCDate()}),this.updateRanges()},updateRanges:function(){var b=a.map(this.dates,function(a){return a.valueOf()});a.each(this.pickers,function(a,c){c.setRange(b)})},dateUpdated:function(b){if(!this.updating){this.updating=!0;var c=a(b.target).data("datepicker"),d=c.getUTCDate(),e=a.inArray(b.target,this.inputs),f=e-1,g=e+1,h=this.inputs.length;if(-1!==e){if(a.each(this.pickers,function(a,b){b.getUTCDate()||b.setUTCDate(d)}),d<this.dates[f])for(;f>=0&&d<this.dates[f];)this.pickers[f--].setUTCDate(d);else if(d>this.dates[g])for(;h>g&&d>this.dates[g];)this.pickers[g++].setUTCDate(d);this.updateDates(),delete this.updating}}},remove:function(){a.map(this.pickers,function(a){a.remove()}),delete this.element.data().datepicker}};var l=a.fn.datepicker,m=function(c){var d=Array.apply(null,arguments);d.shift();var e;return this.each(function(){var f=a(this),i=f.data("datepicker"),l="object"==typeof c&&c;if(!i){var m=g(this,"date"),o=a.extend({},n,m,l),p=h(o.language),q=a.extend({},n,p,m,l);if(f.hasClass("input-daterange")||q.inputs){var r={inputs:q.inputs||f.find("input").toArray()};f.data("datepicker",i=new k(this,a.extend(q,r)))}else f.data("datepicker",i=new j(this,q))}return"string"==typeof c&&"function"==typeof i[c]&&(e=i[c].apply(i,d),e!==b)?!1:void 0}),e!==b?e:this};a.fn.datepicker=m;var n=a.fn.datepicker.defaults={autoclose:!1,beforeShowDay:a.noop,beforeShowMonth:a.noop,calendarWeeks:!1,clearBtn:!1,toggleActive:!1,daysOfWeekDisabled:[],datesDisabled:[],endDate:1/0,forceParse:!0,format:"mm/dd/yyyy",keyboardNavigation:!0,language:"en",minViewMode:0,multidate:!1,multidateSeparator:",",orientation:"auto",rtl:!1,startDate:-1/0,startView:0,todayBtn:!1,todayHighlight:!1,weekStart:0,disableTouchKeyboard:!1,enableOnReadonly:!0,container:"body"},o=a.fn.datepicker.locale_opts=["format","rtl","weekStart"];a.fn.datepicker.Constructor=j;var p=a.fn.datepicker.dates={en:{days:["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"],daysShort:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"],daysMin:["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa","Su"],months:["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],monthsShort:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],today:"Today",clear:"Clear"}},q={modes:[{clsName:"days",navFnc:"Month",navStep:1},{clsName:"months",navFnc:"FullYear",navStep:1},{clsName:"years",navFnc:"FullYear",navStep:10}],isLeapYear:function(a){return a%4===0&&a%100!==0||a%400===0},getDaysInMonth:function(a,b){return[31,q.isLeapYear(a)?29:28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][b]},validParts:/dd?|DD?|mm?|MM?|yy(?:yy)?/g,nonpunctuation:/[^ -\/:-@\[\u3400-\u9fff-`{-~\t\n\r]+/g,parseFormat:function(a){var b=a.replace(this.validParts,"\x00").split("\x00"),c=a.match(this.validParts);if(!b||!b.length||!c||0===c.length)throw new Error("Invalid date format.");return{separators:b,parts:c}},parseDate:function(d,e,f){function g(){var a=this.slice(0,m[k].length),b=m[k].slice(0,a.length);return a.toLowerCase()===b.toLowerCase()}if(!d)return b;if(d instanceof Date)return d;"string"==typeof e&&(e=q.parseFormat(e));var h,i,k,l=/([\-+]\d+)([dmwy])/,m=d.match(/([\-+]\d+)([dmwy])/g);if(/^[\-+]\d+[dmwy]([\s,]+[\-+]\d+[dmwy])*$/.test(d)){for(d=new Date,k=0;k<m.length;k++)switch(h=l.exec(m[k]),i=parseInt(h[1]),h[2]){case"d":d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+i);break;case"m":d=j.prototype.moveMonth.call(j.prototype,d,i);break;case"w":d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+7*i);break;case"y":d=j.prototype.moveYear.call(j.prototype,d,i)}return c(d.getUTCFullYear(),d.getUTCMonth(),d.getUTCDate(),0,0,0)}m=d&&d.match(this.nonpunctuation)||[],d=new Date;var n,o,r={},s=["yyyy","yy","M","MM","m","mm","d","dd"],t={yyyy:function(a,b){return a.setUTCFullYear(b)},yy:function(a,b){return a.setUTCFullYear(2e3+b)},m:function(a,b){if(isNaN(a))return a;for(b-=1;0>b;)b+=12;for(b%=12,a.setUTCMonth(b);a.getUTCMonth()!==b;)a.setUTCDate(a.getUTCDate()-1);return a},d:function(a,b){return a.setUTCDate(b)}};t.M=t.MM=t.mm=t.m,t.dd=t.d,d=c(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(),0,0,0);var u=e.parts.slice();if(m.length!==u.length&&(u=a(u).filter(function(b,c){return-1!==a.inArray(c,s)}).toArray()),m.length===u.length){var v;for(k=0,v=u.length;v>k;k++){if(n=parseInt(m[k],10),h=u[k],isNaN(n))switch(h){case"MM":o=a(p[f].months).filter(g),n=a.inArray(o[0],p[f].months)+1;break;case"M":o=a(p[f].monthsShort).filter(g),n=a.inArray(o[0],p[f].monthsShort)+1}r[h]=n}var w,x;for(k=0;k<s.length;k++)x=s[k],x in r&&!isNaN(r[x])&&(w=new Date(d),t[x](w,r[x]),isNaN(w)||(d=w))}return d},formatDate:function(b,c,d){if(!b)return"";"string"==typeof c&&(c=q.parseFormat(c));var e={d:b.getUTCDate(),D:p[d].daysShort[b.getUTCDay()],DD:p[d].days[b.getUTCDay()],m:b.getUTCMonth()+1,M:p[d].monthsShort[b.getUTCMonth()],MM:p[d].months[b.getUTCMonth()],yy:b.getUTCFullYear().toString().substring(2),yyyy:b.getUTCFullYear()};e.dd=(e.d<10?"0":"")+e.d,e.mm=(e.m<10?"0":"")+e.m,b=[];for(var f=a.extend([],c.separators),g=0,h=c.parts.length;h>=g;g++)f.length&&b.push(f.shift()),b.push(e[c.parts[g]]);return b.join("")},headTemplate:'<thead><tr><th class="prev">&#171;</th><th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch"></th><th class="next">&#187;</th></tr></thead>',contTemplate:'<tbody><tr><td colspan="7"></td></tr></tbody>',footTemplate:'<tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today"></th></tr><tr><th colspan="7" class="clear"></th></tr></tfoot>'};q.template='<div class="datepicker"><div class="datepicker-days"><table class=" table-condensed">'+q.headTemplate+"<tbody></tbody>"+q.footTemplate+'</table></div><div class="datepicker-months"><table class="table-condensed">'+q.headTemplate+q.contTemplate+q.footTemplate+'</table></div><div class="datepicker-years"><table class="table-condensed">'+q.headTemplate+q.contTemplate+q.footTemplate+"</table></div></div>",a.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal=q,a.fn.datepicker.noConflict=function(){return a.fn.datepicker=l,this},a.fn.datepicker.version="1.4.0",a(document).on("focus.datepicker.data-api click.datepicker.data-api",'[data-provide="datepicker"]',function(b){var c=a(this);c.data("datepicker")||(b.preventDefault(),m.call(c,"show"))}),a(function(){m.call(a('[data-provide="datepicker-inline"]'))})}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: have you added css file?

Comment: Give us your code!!!

Comment: @praguan you can find my code above

Comment: @DharaParmar you can find my code above

Comment: @praguan i am already di it

Comment: @praguan i am already do it and it's work fine but the calendar  does not display properly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to add css scripts too

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

//You should to include all jq library into head tag
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```